# I'm trying to get an object from the dictionary by its number

Tags: python, dictionary

The `new_worker` function creates a new `Employee` object and adds it to the `Workers` dictionary by the `worker_number` value. The next `get_worker_by_id` function should get the given object, but the program gives a KeyError.

```
from employee import Employee
Workers = {}
def main():
    new_worker()
    get_worker_by_id()

    

def new_worker():
    worker_name = input('Введите имя сотрудника: ')
    worker_number = input('Введите его номер: ')
    worker_depart = input('Введите его отдел: ')
    worker_post = input('Введите его должность: ')
    Workers[worker_number] = Employee(worker_name, worker_number, worker_depart, worker_post)

def get_worker_by_id():
    id = (input('Чтобы найти сотрудника введите введите его номер: '))
    print(Workers[id])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, number, depart, post):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number = number
        self.__depart = depart
        self.__post = post

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def set_depart(self, depart):
        self.__depart = depart

    def set_post(self, post):
        self.__post = post

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

    def get_depart(self):
        return self.__depart
    
    def get_post(self):
        return self.__post

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Имя сотрудника: ' + self.__name() \
        + '\nНомер сотрудника: ' + self.__number \
        + '\nОтдел сотрудника: ' + self.__depart \
        + '\nДолжность сотрудника: ' + self.__post
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate - the code works fine for me, other than some unrelated errors: in `__str__` function, it should be `self.__name` not `self.__name()`. The `KeyError` could maybe be because of the extra brackets around your `input` function in `get_worker_by_id` - try removing it?

Comment: Your Workers dictionary is keyed on the value entered as worker_number. If the id entered doesn't exist in the dictionary you'll get a KeyError exception. Also, *id* is a Python built-in therefore you shouldn't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below function

```py
def get_worker_by_id():
    id = (input('Чтобы найти сотрудника введите введите его номер: '))
    print(Workers[id]) # <---- This line
```

If you input an `id` which is not already added to the `Workers` dictionary, you'll need to handle that. You can use 2 methods -

1. Try-except

```py
def get_worker_by_id():
    id = (input('Чтобы найти сотрудника введите введите его номер: '))
    try:
        print(Workers[id])
    except KeyError:
        print("Worker does not exists")
```

2. Use `.get()` method for dictionaries

```py
def get_worker_by_id():
    id = (input('Чтобы найти сотрудника введите введите его номер: '))
    print(Workers.get(id, "Worker does not exists"))
```

Also, I can see in `Employee Class`, `__str__` method

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Имя сотрудника: ' + self.__name() \  # <---- This line
        + '\nНомер сотрудника: ' + self.__number \
        + '\nОтдел сотрудника: ' + self.__depart \
        + '\nДолжность сотрудника: ' + self.__post
```

Remove function call (`self.__name() -> self.__name`) as __name is a class variable and not a function!

One more thing, do not use variable `id` as it's a built-in function in python and you are essentially overriding it. Try using `worker_id` instead! :)